# VB/C# .NET: ChartArea x-axis, numbers wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net

I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this challenge:

I have a ChartArea that is fed with data. It used to be 1 data point per meter. So a 5.000 meter measurement had 5.000 data points and 0 to 5000 on the x-axis automatically.

Now the resolution of our measurement device can be changed. So I could get 10.000 data points on a 20km measurement, because the device resolution is set to 2. (one data point per 2 meter).

In this case, my x-axis has labels from 0 to 10.000 (amount of data points). But it should be 0 to 20.000 of course. Like 0,2,4,6,8.....20.000 right?

How could the x-axis be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not work for me:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2
```

It only seems to change the amount of labels shown on the x-axis, not the value.

I got it working though. Before I used..

```
Series(0).Points.AddY(data(I))
```

But I changed it to..

```
Series(0).Points.AddXY(I*Double.Parse(resolution), dots(I))
```

Like you said, where resolution is a string containing "2.0"

Answer (score 0):

You'd first try to get  `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2` or what ever you like (e.g. 0.5).

I also like the more precise way to use a XY chart and directly assign your points to the chart, instead of letting the X-Axis doing the magic.

be aware that feeding the chart control with so much points, it will slow down at some point, though you are not able to see all these points on the screen.`